# Bash "declare -A" does not work on macOS

Tags: linux, bash, macos, associative-array

My guess is that Bash is not updated on macOS. When googling update Bash macOS, I keep getting the bug fix patch. Anyway, I need to use associative arrays in macOS Bash where the command:

```
declare -A
```

yields the error:

> -bash: declare: -A: invalid option
>   declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]

I have Yosemite.

Comment: You can use `home brew` to get BASH 4+ version on OSX

Comment: Or you could use zsh, which had associative arrays first (and which is not GPL, so Apple includes newer versions of it.)

Comment: I ran into this, today, installed BASH 4.4 via Homebrew.  I am impressed to see that BASH 4 is much faster than BASH 3.

Comment: BTW, ksh93 is another shell that supports associative arrays (predating zsh's support of same by a solid 6 years) and ships with MacOS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`declare -A` (associative arrays) are a bash 4+ feature.

The OS X bash is likely 3.X.

I don't know that OS X has an official update for bash 4+.

brew/etc. might though.

Comment: Ya I know it is, but I'm surprised that no one has had a need yet to use bash 4 on mac os x.

Comment: @Mr.Student, it's not that nobody has a need, but Apple refuses to ship GPLv3 software, so they stick with ancient versions of bash for licensing reasons.

Comment: after installing bash using homebrew I needed to use the bash version located here ```/usr/local/bin/bash```